# Flutter onItemSearch from openFilterDialog is asking for bool?

Tags: flutter, filter

Regarding filter_list and FilterListDialog, and the `onItemSearch`,
yesterday everything was fine with `onItemSearch: (list, text) => []`,

but today `onItemSearch` wants to be a bool?? I'm getting the following error:

**The return type 'List' isn't a 'bool', as required by the closure's context.**

```
 void openFilterDialog(BuildContext context) async {
  await FilterListDialog.display<Filter>(
    context,
    listData: filterList,
    selectedListData: selectedFilters,
    height: 480,
    hideSearchField: true,
    headlineText: "Program Filter",
    choiceChipLabel: (item) => item.text,
    onItemSearch: (list, text) => list.contains (text),
    validateSelectedItem: (list, val) => list.contains(val),
```

I incorporated @TheMisplacedMechEngineer's changes.
For some reason the "list" from onItemSearch does NOT have a .contains method.
BUT the "list" under `validateSelectedItem` DOES have a .contains method.

Lastly, everywhere "list" comes up as a type: `List<Filter>`, except for onItemSearch ("list" comes up as a type: `Filter`).
When everything was fine last week, "list" was a type: `List<Filter>`, in all occurrences.

Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onItemSearch` requires you to provide a boolean that shows if the item search condition was met

```
onItemSearch: (list, text) => \\perform manipulation of list and text to get a bool,
```

EDIT 1:

The List is of Type `Filter` as defined by the `display<Filter>` method. So please use methods allowed by that class to perform your search logic

EDIT 2:

list inside `onItemSearch` does not have `.contains` because it is not a List of object Filter but instead just the object itself. Meaning you can only use info/methods present in that class and `contains` will not work

Comment: Hi, thanks for replying. I must be missing something else on my end. I did the changes, but now am getting: "The method 'contains' isn't defined for the type 'Filter'. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'contains'."

Comment: hi @Mavrik00 I've edited my answer to answer

Comment: Hi @TheMisplacedMechEngineer, thank you again for replying. I updated my code with your changes, but the "list" under onItemSearch doesn't have a ".contains" method, but the "list" under validateSelectedItem does have a ".contains" method.  Everywhere "list" comes up as a type List<Filter>?, except for onItemSearch ("list" comes up as a type Filter).

Comment: hi @Mavrik00 have updated again :)

Comment: Hi @TheMisplacedMechEngineer, well, I took the "easy" route. I rolled back ```filter_list``` to version 1.0.0 and now all is well (apparently I updated to 1.0.1 and that's when the trouble started). I thank you for your assistance! Apparently I don't have enough rep/street cred to vote, but you have my vote. thank you again!